# Access nse option chain data (public API) using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, automation, request

I want to access following url:
https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY

1. When I directly paste this in browser, it works like charm and gives an JSON object. (try it)
2. Then I tried it with python using jupyter notebook. It worked again. Following code gives same object as in method 1 above.

```
    import requests
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8'}
    url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"
    json_obj = requests.get(nurl, headers = headers).json()
```

3. But when I try accessing it with google app script, I get nothing. It keeps executing request and then timeout occurs after 6 minutes. Below is code for same

```
    var ocurl = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY";
  
    var hds = {
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8',
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
    };

    var params = {headers: hds, followRedirects: false, muteHttpExceptions: true};
    var ocresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(ocurl, params);
    //var data = JSON.parse(ocresponse.getContentText())

    Logger.log(ocresponse.getContentText());
```

My guess is that in first two cases request is going from local browser/server, but in case of third request it is going from servers owned by google. And NSE is blocking those requests. I'm not sure whether this is correct.

I want to use google script because it provides automatic trigger functionality (similar to cron job) and it is free.

Is there any way I can access it with google app script??

Comment: In your script, when `followRedirects: false` is removed, what result will you obtain? By the way, unfortunately, `UrlFetchApp.fetch` of Google Apps Script cannot change `User-Agent`. So if `User-Agent` is required to be changed, I thought that your python script cannot be converted. How about this?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, removing ```followRedirects``` has no effect. Still request is incomplete. I didn't understand part about converting to python script. Can you please explain it?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `I didn't understand part about converting to python script. Can you please explain it?`. In your goal, you want to convert your Google Apps Script to python script. Is my understanding correct? By the way, in your endpoint, is `User-Agent` required to be modified?

Comment: No, I don't want to covert google app script to python script. I want google app script to work which is not working. And as per my understaning, ```User-Agent``` is required to be modified in order to fake request (as if it's coming from a browser).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. As I mentioned in my 1st comment, unfortunately, in the current stage, `UrlFetchApp.fetch` of Google Apps Script cannot change `User-Agent`. So your `User-Agent` in python script cannot be used as  `User-Agent`. I apologize for this. And, as my 1st comment, when `followRedirects: false` is removed, your Google Apps Script is the same request of your python script. But from your replying, it seems that even when you remove it, the request didn't work. I apologize for this again.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike for response. To conclude, If I understand correctly, ```User-Agent``` is causing the problem and it cannot be changed in google app script. It seems there is no workaround for the problem.

Comment: For example, when UrlFetchApp is used, the value of `User-Agent` is like `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)`. In this case, `aaa...` is an ID. So when this value cannot be used for the python script, in the current stage, it is considered that Google Apps Script cannot be used for your situation.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike ! Could you please formalise your comments as an answer so that other users attempting similar things can easily find the answer? Thanks !

Comment: @Mateo Randwolf Thank you for your comment. From your comment, I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Sure, thank you very much for providing this answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to convert the following python script to Google Apps Script,

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br','Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8'}
url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"
json_obj = requests.get(nurl, headers = headers).json()
```

it becomes as follows.

```
var ocurl = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY";
var hds = {
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
};
var params = {headers: hds, muteHttpExceptions: true};
var ocresponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(ocurl, params);
```

But, unfortunately, in the current stage, UrlFetchApp cannot modify `User-Agent`. By this, when above Google Apps Script is run, the value of `User-Agent` is `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script; beanserver; +https://script.google.com; id: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa)` where `aaa...` seems the unique ID. About modifying `User-Agent` using UrlFetchApp, it has already been reported at Google issue tracker as the future request. [Ref](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36758197) Unfortunately, it seems that this has still not been able to be implemented.

From your replying in comments, it seems that `User-Agent` is required to be modified. So, unfortunately, as the current answer, it seems that your goal cannot be achieved using UrlFetchApp.

#### Reference:

- [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Answer (score 1):

I used the following headers and it worked

"Accept", "[asterisk]/[asterisk]"

"Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"

"User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"

"Connection", "keep-alive"